# Почему метод печатает каждый элемент массива на новую строку

Tags: c#, массивы

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, совсем недавно начал изучать книгу Троелсена по C# и .NET, дошел до массивов и немного не понимаю, почему мой созданный метод выводит каждый элемент массива на новую строку, как исправить?:

```
static void JaggedMultidimensionalArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=> Jagged multidimensional array");

        //Здесь мы имеем массив из 5 разных массивов
        int[][] myJagArray = new int[5][];

        //Создать массив
        for (int i = 0; i < myJagArray.Length; i++)
            myJagArray[i] = new int[i + 7];

        //вывести каждую строку
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myJagArray[i].Length; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(myJagArray[i][j] + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Потому что `Console.WriteLine` дописывает символ конца строки. Нужно использовать `Console.Write` либо `Join`

Comment: @slippyk Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 2):

MSDN говорит, что:

> Метод **Console.WriteLine** () записывает текущий признак конца строки в
>   стандартный выходной поток.

Отсюда и вывод каждого элемента с новой строки.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно использовать метод `Console.Write()`, который будет дописывать символы в конец строки без перехода на новую (если не был указан соответствующий символ `\n` или `\r\n`).

Либо использовать метод `string.Join()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", myJagArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: с помощью `LINQ` - `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", myJagArray.Select(x=>string.Join(" ",x))));`

Comment: @FoggyFinder действительно перемудрил по привычке, в `Python` только строковые принимает `Join`

Answer (score 1):

`WriteLine` записывает признак конца строки

`Write` не записывает признак конца строки

```
static void JaggedMultidimensionalArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=> Jagged multidimensional array");

        //Здесь мы имеем массив из 5 разных массивов
        int[][] myJagArray = new int[5][];

        //Создать массив
        for (int i = 0; i < myJagArray.Length; i++)
            myJagArray[i] = new int[i + 7];

        //вывести каждую строку
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < myJagArray[i].Length; j++)
                Console.Write(myJagArray[i][j] + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```